# Get value of dynamic array in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to parse nested dynamic array in jQuery.
 code is :-

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {    // url of the controller
method: 'get',
parameters: { search: searchString }, //parameter 
onComplete: function(transport) {
  alert(transport.responseText);
      var values = transport.responseText;
      alert(values.length);
      // response from the controller will get alerted.
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
for (var x in values[i]){
   console.log(x+"="+values[i][x]);
  }
 }


}
});
```

when I alert array then it show array is something like :-

```
 Array
  (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [post_id] => 1
        [title] => Womens Health
        [post_content] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        [status] => 1
        [created_time] => 2014-01-20 20:15:34
        [update_time] => 2014-02-27 18:51:42
        [identifier] => women_health
        [user] => aheadWorks
        [update_user] => Bod christen
        [meta_keywords] => Must-have Magento Extensions, aheadWorks
        [meta_description] => Must-have Magento Extensions
        [comments] => 0
        [tags] => 
        [short_content] => <p><img src="{{skin url='images/journal.jpeg'}}" alt="" /></p>
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [post_id] => 2
        [title] => Ladies Home Joural
        [post_content] => <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>
        [status] => 1
        [created_time] => 2014-02-17 18:02:54
        [update_time] => 2014-02-27 18:49:46
        [identifier] => ladies_home_joural
        [user] => Bod christen
        [update_user] => Bod christen
        [meta_keywords] => 
        [meta_description] => 
        [comments] => 0
        [tags] => 
        [short_content] => <p><img src="{{skin url='images/journal1.jpeg'}}" alt="" /></p>
    )

 )
```

Comment: A hint.... use `for each` loop. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript

Comment: I am trying to get but it returns undefined

Comment: Post the code you are trying to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Assume you call you array `values`

```
for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
    for (var x in values[i]){
       console.log(x+"="+values[i][x]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but something like this might work:

```
for(var i=0; i < your_array.length; ++i){
    console.log(your_array[i]['title']);
    console.log(your_array[i]['short_content']);
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that he doesn't know that the keys will be title and short_content ... so he cannot code them